# I am building a Chrome extension of a StopWatch but it is getting reset automatically when i click anywhere else

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a stopwatch chrome extension and getting a issue that whenever I click anywhere else in the window(outside extension popup) my stopwatch get reset at 0 but I want that it should be running until I manually turned it off or close the browser.
Help me to solve it

**It is my Manifest.json code**

```
{
"name": "ClockSet",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": "logo.png"
},
"icons": {
    "128": "logo.png"
}}
```

**Here is my JavaScript**

```js
//For Stopwatchconst 
// Timer Field
let hourElement = document.querySelector(".hour");
let minuteElement = document.querySelector(".minute");
let secondElement = document.querySelector(".second");
let millisecondElement = document.querySelector(".milliSecond");

// Button Field
let startButton = document.querySelector(".start");
let pauseButton = document.querySelector(".pause");
let stopButton = document.querySelector(".stop");

// Counter Variable
let hour = 00;
let minute = 00;
let second = 00;
let millisecond = 00;
let interval;

window.onload = () => clearFields();

startButton.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval); // If Some Error Happen and Interval is Setup, It Will Clear That Interval
    interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10); //
};
pauseButton.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval); // On Clicking Pause Buttom We Will Clear Interval
};
stopButton.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval); // Clear Interval
    clearFields(); // Clear Timer Fields
};

function startTimer() {
    millisecond++;
    if (millisecond < 9) {
        millisecondElement.innerText = "0" + millisecond;
    }
    if (millisecond > 99) {
        second++;
        secondElement.innerText = "0" + second;
        millisecond = 0;
        millisecondElement.innerText = "0" + millisecond;
    }
    if (second > 60) {
        minute++;
        minuteElement.innerText = "0" + minute;
        second = 0;
        secondElement.innerText = "0" + second;
    }

    if (millisecond > 9) {
        millisecondElement.innerText = millisecond;
    }
    if (second > 9) {
        secondElement.innerText = second;
    }
    if (minute > 9) {
        minuteElement.innerText = minute;
    }
    if (hour > 9) {
        hourElement.innerText = hour;
    }
}

function clearFields() {
    hourElement.innerText = "00";
    minuteElement.innerText = "00";
    secondElement.innerText = "00";
    millisecondElement.innerText = "00";
}
```

```css
.watch {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="stopwatch">
        <div class="row watch">
            <div class=" col-3 hourDiv">
                <h3 class="hour">01</h3>
                <p class="hourTitle">Hour</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 minuteDiv">
                <h3 class="minute">30</h3>
                <p class="minuteTitle">Min</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 secondDiv">
                <h3 class="second">01</h3>
                <p class="secondTitle">Sec</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 milliSecondDiv">
                <h3 class="milliSecond">99</h3>
                <p class="milliSecondTitle">Millis</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn btn-primary start button" title="Start"><i class="bi bi-play"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary pause button" title="Pause"><i class="bi bi-pause-fill"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary stop button" title="Reset"><i class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise"></i></button>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to run your code in a background script (not the popup script).
The popup script instance dies when the popup is closed like all variables declared inside it.
So the popup script should send a command message to background script to inform whenever the user will push on any button. So the stopwatch will goes on without a opened popup as well.
When the user will open the popup again will ask the background script to return some variables (ms, s, m, h) in order to update the stopwatch.
However this system will only work with manifest V2

Comment: sorry but unable to understand your solution can you please elaborate it clearly I am new in chrome extension development frankly speaking this is my first one

Comment: as starting point you should read these manifest V2 docs:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/architecture-overview/
 and 
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging/